# Adding Websphere portal server 6.1 in RAD 8

Tags: rad, websphere-6.1, websphere-portal

I am facing a problem in adding portal server 6.1 in RAD 8. it says "Could not create an RMI connector to connect to host at port 10031". I even tried to change the RMI port but still doesnt help. It seems the application server hasnt started. I cant start it from cmd and not even from RAD. Am I going wrong anywhere? Plz help.. Its urgent... Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

What do you see as errors in the logs when you start the server from the command line? If it does not start in the command line i wouldn't bother trying to connect it from RAD.